# How I can Pause Order in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

We have a three-day vacation
And I want to pause the Order Magento
How's the way?

Comment: You might need to use order `Hold`|`Unhold` functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One easiest solution:**

1.Create a Cms page and put some content

2.redirect your customer to this cms page when git your checkout page `www.domain.com/checkout/` to `www.domain.com/YOURCMSPAGE/`.
For creating this redirection Goto `Admin>Marketing>Url Rewrite` by clicking  "Add Rewrite"

> - **`Create URL Rewrite: type should be: Custom`**
> - **`Request Path : checkout`**
> - **`Target Path : YourCMSPageIdenetifier`**
> - **`Redirect Type: Permanent (301)`**

[image]
**OR**

Just to got ***admin>Store>Configuration>Sales>Checkout>Checkout Options***

**Make Enable Onepage Checkout IS `NO`**

[image]